# Convergence of matrix and norm equivalence

Tags: general-topology, matrices, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

In textbook related to matrix analysis, when the concept of convergence of matrix is dealt, they give the topology using a norm. Since every norm is equivalent for finite dimensional vector space, we have only to pick a norm and observe the analytic things. However, there must exist a topology such that convergence situation which happens in above topology from a norm does not occur.
My question is 'why do the books related to matrix analysis only consider topology from a norm when they discuss the concept of convergence?'.

Comment: What other norm you would consider? For infinite-dimensional spaces, there are several distinct topologies on the space of all (bounded linear) operators, but they all coincide in the finite-dimensional case. They also coincide with the topology given by identifying a linear map with its matrix in a fixed basis. I don't know of any interesting topologies on matrices other than the standard one. I think if anything, it would be more interesting to consider different metrics.

Comment: To make it clear, I'm not claiming there are *no* other topologies at all, just that there are no (widely known to be) interesting ones.

Comment: Thank you! It makes me clarify.